# How can I implement UnitOfWork, Repository Pattern, Unity and EF with Thread Safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, unity-container, unit-of-work

I'm thinking something like this:

```
IUoW oUoW = oUnity.Resolve<IUoW>(); //<-- New Context here (Life per resolve).
var oNewEntity = new SomeEntity{ name = "somethink ... "};

oUoW.oSomeEntity.Add( oNewEntity);
oUoW.SaveChanges();

oUoW.Dispose();//<-- delete context.
```

But how can I resolve the instance for "oUoW.oSomeEntity", I could need to do a Resolve in the constructor or not...

Another way I'm thinking

```
IUoW oUoW = oUnity.Resolve<IUoW>(); //<-- New Context here (Life per resolve).
var oNewEntity = new SomeEntity{ name = "somethink ... "};

oSomeEntityRepository = oUnity.Resolve<ISomeEntityRepository>();//Ugly way
oSomeEntityRepository.oUoW = oUoW;//Ugly way

oSomeEntityRepository.Add( oNewEntity);
oUoW.SaveChanges();

oUoW.Dispose();//<-- Delete context.

... Open Another Context ...
```

That's code is not thread safe 100%, but I would short instances of context

Do you think another way?
I'll Do Unit Test now ...

To thread safe I'm thinking in another method that use a Mutex ... something like...

```
IUoW oUoW = oUnity.Resolve<IUoW>();
oUoW.MutexLock();

... save, delete, linq ...

oUoW.MutexUnlok();
```

mmm .... &%$··%&·!&$%&...mmm LAPSUS

Comment: What is your application ? Web , service ? It would be useful to know . Is the consuming code you have above created per thread?

Comment: Of topic but why prefix everything with 'o'? apart from it making your code sound like a ghost when you read it aloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've edited a template that auto-generate a UnitOfWork, Context, Repository, And FactoryUnitOfWork http://pastebin.com/6D2X5Ykp, you need to edit the template to change the entity model if you do it in a separate dll.

To use the Pattern:
Register in Composition Root:

```
IUnityContainer uc = new UnityContainer();
yourdaonamespace.CompositionRoot.Init( uc );
```

And to use:

```
using (var oIUoW = this.IFactoryUnitOfWork.Resolve())
{
    var YOURENTITYFoundedFromRepository = oIUoW.oRepositoryENTITY.First(o => o.iYourProperty == 1);
}

//more code 
using (var oIUoW = this.IFactoryUnitOfWork.Resolve())
{ 
   var entity = new domain.YOURENTITY()
   {
       sYourProperty = "TEST ENTITY"
   };
   uow.oRepositoryYOURENTITY.Insert(entity);
   uow.Commit();
}
```

**Requirement**: Your need to generate the YOURMODEL.edmx

**NOTE**: The Template Is Temporal In Pastebin, Could Anyone Help With Permanent Template, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have your uow resolved, repositories should be direct properties of the uow:

```
IUoW oUoW = oUnity.Resolve<IUoW>(); //<-- New Context here (Life per resolve).
var oNewEntity = new SomeEntity{ name = "somethink ... "};

oSomeEntityRepository = uow.SomeEntityRepository;//Not ugly at all
```

Since most example implementations follow this idea, I wonder what your implementation is.

Anyway, it goes like

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
     private ISomeEntityRepository _someEntityRepository;
     public ISomeEntityRepository SomeEntityRepository
     {
         get
         {
              if ( _someEntityRepository == null )
                    _someEntityRepository = new ...
              return _someEntityRepository;
         }
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be. UoW is resolved, repositories in the uow don't have to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

@Wiktor Zychla is right but I his example implemetation can confuse you. If you are using a DI container, like Unity here, repositories should be injected in UOW when UOW is resolved; and a single DBContext instance injected in UOW (to call saveChanges) and in all repositores resolved (I assume that your UOW has multiple repositories becuase if not, you do not need UOW). This is know as "cascade injection" and is the butter and bread of using a DI container.

This way you can make multiple changes in Database using multiple repositories (one for aggregate root) to finish a use case and only a single UOW.Savechanges needed.

Comment: I don't quite agree. A concrete uow type means concrete repositories and thus you don't really need to resolve repositories if you resolve a uow. I believe you try to misuse the DI here by putting too much responsibility into it and making too many components directly depending on it.

Comment: Yes, I think so, but with unit test for example, I would to make two UoW
, that could be a good idea, although is less flexible, 

If I want to change Implementation of one Repository
, I'll need to change the UoW implementation and not the composition root.

Is far that happen, but could be, ... for the moment I follow your idea, Thanks

Comment: Loose coupling in UOW and repositories is a good idea. As the OP says any implementation thas makes you touch a class just becase a dependecy changes violates SOLID rules.